# Get claim id of user in SharePoint 2010 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, claims

Is it possible to get the "id" of the current user in SharePoint 2010 with javascript ? It must be the ID that is located in a claim in the page.

Is this ID the same as : _spPageContextInfo.userId?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

_spPageContextInfo.userId will return the Id of the current user as it is stored within the User Information List for the current site collection.  It's the same ID you would see if you were to view the user profile within SharePoint and look at the URL which contains the same ID as a parameter.